# Github account login without SSH key or Two Factor Auth

Tags: authentication, github, ssh, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I have Two-factor authentication enabled on my Github account so that an authentication code is sent to my phone and from there I can login with that code. However, I just got a new phone, and all of my two-factor authenticator (Google Authenticator) app data was cleared. To add back the github account to my Authenticator, I need a QR code only accessed by being logged into github.

I clicked on Recover my Account, verified my email with a temporary code, and got to step 2 which is...'Verify a device, SSH key or personal access token'. The only option the screen gives me is to verify via SSH. However, since I have a new laptop, my SSH key I just created isn't the one that is linked to my account in Github. I never saved any of the recovery codes either. Hopefully I'm not totally out of luck?

Comment: probably a blond question, but you don't have access to your old phone or laptop?

Comment: I wish. The Verizon store wiped my phone and the IT department wiped my old laptop. Darn

Comment: This question might be better directed at github support. The short answer is to always make sure you securely store the recovery codes for any two-factor auth in case you lose access to your phone for any reason.

Comment: I agree! I learned my lesson on this one. And yes, I sent a message to github support as well. Thank you!

Comment: I wish you good luck!